# Create a table in SQL Server from a tables values

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, join

Ok, Stay with me here and lets see if anyone knows if this can be done.
I initially query a table to bring back just 1 row, this row has the data that I will use.
What I need to do is, convert that 1 row to a table where each column value is aligned with what the column name was.

So I query a table to get 1 row, say a table called colours and in it there are the columns Name, Hue, Populatiry.

I need to get that 1 row to be a table where the values of lets say:

```
Red, 50, Super Popular
```

Become a table of:

```
Name, Red
Hue, 50
Populatiry, Super Popular
```

Im basically using a function to replace a string value (entered as a what a columns name is) with its actual value and I cannot use the exec command as functions wont allow it and it has to be a function cause Im selecting that returned string directly into a procedure:

This is the code I had until I found exec commands stop it working as a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[GetOutlookTrainingBodyText]
(
    @ScheduleID bigint
)
RETURNS nvarchar(300)
AS
BEGIN

    declare c cursor local fast_forward
    for
    SELECT Label, Name, QueryField
    FROM IntranetPagesx ipx
    INNER JOIN IntranetPageLayoutx ipl on ipl.PageID = ipx.PageID
    WHERE ipx.PageID = 'Training Attendance'

    declare @name nvarchar (100)
    declare @name1 nvarchar (100)
    declare @label nvarchar (100)
    declare @queryfield nvarchar (200)
    declare @sql nvarchar (1000)
    declare @BodyText nvarchar(500) = (SELECT dbo.GetValidSystemPropertyValue('OutlookIntegrationTrainingBodyTextTemplate'))

    open c
    fetch next from c into @label, @name, @queryfield

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin

        SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 @name1= '+@queryfield+' FROM TRAINING_AttendanceConfirmed WHERE ScheduleID = ''246'''
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@name1 nvarchar(200) out', @name1 out
        set @BodyText = Replace(@BodyText, '#'+@label+'#', (ISNULL(@name1, '')))

    fetch next from c into @label, @name, @queryfield
    END
    CLOSE c
    DEALLOCATE c

    PRINT @BodyText
return (@BodyText)

END
```

I need the working equivalent without the use of exec - can this be done????

Comment: If I understand well `Label` is what you want to be the field name and  `QueryField` the column in your table where the value is. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

xml can provide some flexibility to handle column names and values, something like this:

```
SELECT 
CAST(CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM colours FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML).query('fn:local-name(*[1]/.)') AS VARCHAR(100)) colname,
CAST(CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM colours FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML).query('*[1]/text()') AS VARCHAR(100)) value
UNION
SELECT 
CAST(CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM colours FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML).query('fn:local-name(*[2]/.)') AS VARCHAR(100)) colname,
CAST(CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM colours FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML).query('*[2]/text()') AS VARCHAR(100)) value
UNION
SELECT 
CAST(CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM colours FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML).query('fn:local-name(*[3]/.)') AS VARCHAR(100)) colname,
CAST(CAST((SELECT TOP 1 * FROM colours FOR XML PATH('')) AS XML).query('*[3]/text()') AS VARCHAR(100)) value
```